# scanf("%[^\n]s",a) with set size of string

Tags: c, scanf

So I had a code where I use 
scanf("%[^\n]s",a); 
and has multiple scanf to take different inputs some being string input. So I understand that scanf("%[^\n]s",a) takes input until new line has been reached, however I was wondering suppose my string can only hold up to 10 characters, then after my string has been filled, but new line hasn't been reached how can i get rid of the extra input before going to new line. I was thinking of doing getchar() until new line has been reached however in order to even check if my 10 spots has been filled I need to use getchar, so doesn't that mess up my next scanf input? Anybody have any other way to do it? Still using scanf() and getchar?

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%[^\n]s",a)` is a common mistake; the `%[` directive is distinct from the `%s` directive. What you're asking from `scanf` is:

- A group of non-`'\n'` characters, followed by...
- A literal `s` character.

Perhaps you intended to write `scanf("%[^\n]",a)`? Note the deleted `s`...

You can use the `*` modifier to suppress assignment for a directive, for example `scanf("%10[^\n]", a);` followed by `scanf("%*[^\n]");` to read and discard up to the next newline and `getchar();` to read and discard that newline:

```
scanf("%10[^\n]", a);
scanf("%*[^\n]");     // read and discard up to the next newline
getchar();            // read and discard that newline
```

As pointed out, the two format strings could be concatenated to reduce the number of calls to `scanf`. I wrote my answer this way for the sake of documentation, and I'll leave it as is. Besides, I figure that attempt at optimisation would be negligible; a profiler is likely to indicate much more significant bottlenecks for optimisation in realistic scenarios.

Comment: Why not combining two `scanf` into one. One more call is more space in the stack.

Comment: @Meninx I don't believe you. Please show me within the C standard draft n1570.pdf, where is this "stack" mentioned?

Comment: The first scanf would read up to size of my string, then it would discard anything after that up to the new line and the getchar would move to the next line right? However, if the user enters data less than 10 and I want to read in data from the next line too, wouldn't the scanf("%*[^\n]"); and getchar(); skip some of the input following the first input?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format to hold the first 10 characters and keep the **next lines** of input:

```
scanf("%10[^\n]%*[^\n]",a);
getchar();
```

Comment: So if the input exceeds 10 characters on the first line, this way it would just skip the rest of the characters on the line and go to next line? I'm new to C so i'm just confused about the formatting.

Comment: Exactly, **rest of character** on that line will be skipped.

Comment: This won't read and discard the `'\n'` when the set read and discarded by `%*[^\n]` is empty, as that empty set causes failure which causes `scanf` to return immediately. Citation: "Matches a non-empty sequence of bytes from a set of expected bytes (the scanset)." and "Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure." -- [opengroup fscanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html)

Comment: I agree on that if the next `scanf` will use `%[` so `getchar()` is the right thing to include this case.

Comment: @NishR If you're new to C, you should probably read (and understand) [the opengroup `fscanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) in it's entirety... even if you don't understand *parts* of it, persist!

Comment: `a terminating null byte, which shall be added automatically.
`

Comment: Exactly, that's why you have to put in the format string a number that is one less then the number of allocated chars.

Comment: @Bob__ according to that OP should **define** the variable `a` with the corresponding size. My format is correct.